# Move s3 entire bucket from IntelligentTiering to STANDARD + Permanently unarchive the entire bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, aws-cli

I have a bucket with few milions objects with IntelligentTiering configuration accidentally applied and placed some files in Glacier.

Any ideas how to:

1. Move s3 entire bucket from IntelligentTiering to STANDARD
2. Permanently unarchive the frozen objects in the entire bucket

Comment: [Restore Amazon S3 object from Amazon Glacier storage class](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/restore-s3-object-glacier-storage-class/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar situation and it's not straightforward. I was backing up my camera photos in Glacier tier and was not able to convert it. However, using CLI you can follow these steps to get it done.

**STEP 1 - RESTORE OBJECTS**

`aws s3api restore-object --bucket bucketName --restore-request '{"Days":4,"GlacierJobParameters":{"Tier":"Standard"}}' --key "folderStructureToBeRestored/"`

**STEP 2 - CHECK HEAD** (Do it periodically every hour to find if restore is completed by AWS)

`aws s3api head-object --bucket bucketName --key "folderStructureToBeRestored/"`

**STEP 3 - CHANGE TIER**

`aws s3 cp s3://bucketName/path s3://bucketName/newPath --storage-class STANDARD --recursive --force-glacier-transfer`

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Move s3 entire bucket from IntelligentTiering to STANDARD

S3 lifecycles will [not work](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/lifecycle-transition-general-considerations.html) for that. So you have to do it "manually". I would look at [S3 Batch Operations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/batch-ops.html):

> Use S3 Batch Operations to copy objects and set object tags or access control lists (ACLs). You can also initiate object **restores from Amazon S3 Glacier** or invoke an AWS Lambda function to perform custom actions using your objects.

[Copy objects](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/batch-ops-copy-object.html) actions allows for "changing an object's storage class".

> 2. Permanently unarchive the frozen objects in the entire bucket

S3 Batch could also be used.